# What is the type of a Storage::download($path); response in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use type declaration in my Laravel controller for a method that returns this :

`return Storage::disk('s3')->download($file->path, $file->name);`

Which class should I use? I couldn't find it in the doc.

Comment: It's in [`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php), and it returns `@return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse` according to its phpdoc

Comment: For future reference, Laravel has a documentation API that you can search for any class and see available properties, methods, return types, extensions, etc.: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/index.html. In your case: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Storage.html#method_download. If you hover over `static StreamedResponse`, it shows `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse` 